# Why does my \hbar look like this?

Tags: math-operators, unicode-math, amssymb

[image]

This `\hbar` is ugly with the bar too high and too left

[image]

This is what I want

My settings are:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[ball]
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{series=\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}
\setCJKsansfont{SimSun}[BoldFont=Noto Sans CJK SC Medium]
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=green,
    urlcolor=cyan,
    citecolor=cyan,
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\uglyepsilon\epsilon
  \renewcommand\epsilon{\varepsilon}
}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\uglymathsf\mathsf
  \renewcommand\mathsf{\symsf}
}

\let\sectiononly\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \sectiononly{#1}
    \let\sectiontitle\relax
    \newcommand{\sectiontitle}{#1}
}

\newenvironment{slide}{
    \begin{frame}{\bfseries{\sectiontitle}}
}{
    \end{frame}
}
```

what is next is: if I add:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{bold-style=ISO, mathrm=sym}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\renewcommand{\bm}{\symbf}
```

to my settings, it will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unicode-math` by default uses Latin Modern Math as the math mode font which is why the `\hbar` looks different. To access the original Computer Modern `\hbar` you can do something like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\let\oldhbar\hbar % Computer Modern hbar
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\let\newhbar\hbar % Latin Modern hbar

\begin{document}
\def\hbar{\oldhbar\mkern1mu} % hbar kerning redefinition
\[\hbar\]
\end{document}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! So LMM and CM have different `\hbar`, but your code produces an `h`

Comment: Oh, sorry! I fixed the code now :)